# using javascript to assign value to model

Tags: c#, jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm using a calendar and I need to pass the value from it into my model to be submitted back to the controller but i'm stuck.

View

```
<div class="cell">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpectedDatetimeStamp, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }):
    <div data-role="calendar" data-week-start="1" data-multi-select="false" id="c1" class="calendar"></div>
        <div hidden>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpectedDatetimeStamp)</div>
    <div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpectedDatetimeStamp)
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="button primary" />
</div>
```

JS

```
function get_dates(){
    var result = $("#c1").calendar('getDates');
    alert(result);
}
```

how can I assign the value from result to `model.ExpectedDatetimeStamp` when the user presses the submit button?

Comment: `$('#ExpectedDatetimeStamp').val(result);`

Comment: HA ok so the ID's of each item is the var name? Please post as answer so I can except it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comments, each item in your model is given a name that matches its name in the model.  So for example, your item `ExpectedDatetimeStamp` would have an element with that name.

So to set the value, simply use:

```
$('#ExpectedDatetimeStamp').val(result);
```

And done! :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML helper you use will assign the input the id of `ExpectedDatetimeStamp`. Simply target it in your get dates function, and attach that function in the callback of a submit event on the closest form to the .cell element. If you are using MomentJS, then the call to calendar should be `getDate`. Further, in order to properly assign a value to the input as opposed to the moment object, you may want to use `.format()`

```
function get_dates(){
 var result = $("#c1").calendar('getDate').format();
 $('#ExpectedDatetimeStamp').val(result)
}

$('.cell').closest('form').submit(function(){
 //..any other values that need to be populated
 get_dates();
});
```